# iMessage: How to tell which conversations sent from phone or email?

Tags: messages

I have my phone and email activated on iMessage. Some of my conversations are sent from my email and some are sent from my phone.

How can I tell which conversations are sent from which address (phone or email)?

In other words, if I open a conversation in iMessage, how do I tell whether it is associated with my phone number or my email address?

Related question, how can I tell whether the other person in the conversation is receiving it at their phone or email (it just shows the contact card for the other person, no indication whether it's to phone or email).

I have iMessage on my iPhone (iOS 13.3.1) and MacBook Pro (macOS 10.15.6), same question/issue on both platforms.

Comment: By email you mean Apple ID, right?

Comment: I beleive that messages sent via iCloud/email show up as blue whereas green colors denote SMS messages which are strictly a function of your phone number.

Comment: @steve chambers, if you and the recipient both have an iPhone, it will appear as an iMessage (blue message) by default even if you are texting directly from the number and not from the iCloud/email address. It is possible to disable iMessages entirely and just use SMS but this applies to all your contacts, so all your recipients will see it as an SMS (green message). I think the question is how to distinguish between them sending via iCloud (say from  a Mac/iPad) and from an iPhone using their mobile number